# Prove that $ I = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $ I_0 \subseteq I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3...$ be a sequence of ideals of a commutative ring $R$. In other words for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$  assume $I_k$ is an ideal of $R$ and that $I_k \subseteq I_{k+1}$ for every $k \ge 0$. Prove that $ I = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k$ is an ideal of $R$.

How do I go about proving that for all $k$,  $I_k$ absorbs products?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2):

**I is closed under the action of $R$**

Let $x\in I$ and $r\in R$. Then $x\in I_k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and thus $rx \in I_k \subset I$, since $I_k$ is an ideal.

---

**I is closed under addition**

Now let $x,y\in I$. We may assume that $x \in I_k$ and $y\in I_j$ with $I_j \subseteq I_k$. Then $x,y\in I_k$ and hence $x+y\in I_k \subset I$ since $I_k$ is an ideal.

---

Hence $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prove $I_k$ absorbs products.  You are told to *assume* each $I_k$ is an ideal.  So you already know $I_k$ is an ideal, and in particular it absorbs products.